# (Smart) pointers to a base class storing derived objects; is this correct & good practis?

Tags: pointers, c++11, inheritance, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast

I have the following piece of code where I have a smart pointer of a base class type `unique_ptr<Animal>`. But I'd like to store a derived object with it `new Bird()`. Since it is a pointer this works well. Is this good practise or will I run into problem during expanding my code?

Next, I like to call methods of the derived object: `eat()`. Hence I need to convert the pointer to be of the derived type. Is this use of dynamic_cast correct? Are there any solutions that might fit better for this problem (Problem: I do not know which kind of object I have)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual void move() {cout<<"ooopsooops\n";}
};

class Fish : public Animal{
public:
    Fish() {}
    void move() {cout<<"swimswim\n";}
};

class Bird : public Animal{
public:
    Bird() {}
    void move() {cout<<"flyfly\n";}
    void eat() {cout<<"pickpick\n";}
};


int main()
{
    Animal().move(); //ooopsooops | good!

    Animal* ptr(new Bird());
    ptr->move(); //flyfly | perfect!

    unique_ptr<Animal> s_ptr(new Bird());
    s_ptr->move(); //flyfly | perfect!

    vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new Animal());
    v.emplace_back(new Fish());
    v.emplace_back(new Bird());

    for(auto& i : v)
        i->move(); //ooopsooops | swimswim | flyfly | exellent!

    //v.at(2)->eat(); Does not work -> use dynamic_cast

    auto d_ptr(dynamic_cast<Bird*>(v.at(2).get()));
    if(d_ptr)
        d_ptr->eat(); //pickpick | very good!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour since `Animal` does not have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is really not recommended, your code (with the `dynamic_cast`) precisely undoes the benefits that inheritance is designed to give you, namely *not* needing to know what object's class is.  This looks like a practice example, but taking it at face value, all animals eat so that should be a method in your base class.  This base class should moreover be abstract if calling `Animal::move` is really an 'oops'.  In addition you omit `virtual` in your derived classes which is at least a design error.  So I'd redo along these lines:

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual void eat() = 0;
    virtual void move() = 0;
};

class Fish : public Animal{
public:
    Fish() {}
    virtual void eat() override {cout<<"eateat\n";}
    virtual void move() override {cout<<"swimswim\n";}
};

class Bird : public Animal{
public:
    Bird() {}
    virtual void eat() override {cout<<"pickpick\n";}
    virtual void move() override {cout<<"flyfly\n";}
};
```

Note the use of the `override` specifier which is very useful for catching inheritance errors at compile time.  You will no longer be able to write `Animal().move();` but that's okay; if you really want a concrete base class then put what I have in `Animal` above into an `AnimalBase` class and redesign `Animal` as desired.